# What are the security concerns of saving a JSON as is in ABAP?

Tags: json, rest, abap

I have an SICF service (ReST service). This service accepts POST requests and the incoming JSON is persisted in an ABAP DDIC table *as is* (without any ABAP conversion) in a RAWSTRING. Are there any security concerns of doing such a thing?
If yes, how do we avoid it?

Comment: Caching is commonplace in most REST applications. I don't see any particular reason why you shouldn't do it unless somehow it exposes sensitive information, which is very case specific.

Comment: This information will be persisted in the Database - not just in the cache. And there's no sensitive info

Comment: No inherent security concerns to the action of storing this data alone. The only risk you run there is to be using outdated information.

Comment: Depends on what kind of information you store. `RAWSTRING` fields can be easily read with direct acess to DB.